# Python/shapely: unary_union raises AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute '_geom'

Tags: python, shapely

I am updating from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6. I have code that worked before and now raises an error where it uses `shapely.ops.unary_union()`. The argument used with that call is a GeoJSON object

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 
 'features': [
     {'geometry': 
         {'type': 'Polygon', 
          'coordinates': (((389331.5078411353, 5521519.426939811), (389331.9797582473, 5521513.321540129), (389330.07324640994, 5521514.852591204), (389331.5078411353, 5521519.426939811)),)}, 
          'type': 'Feature', 
          'properties': 
              {'ZoneMean': 0.35, 
               'FERTILITY_': 'VR', 
               'PolyArea': 0.0,
               'ZoneID': 6,
               'ZoneMin': 0.26,
               'id_1': 0.0, 
               'PolyMean': 0.35, 
               'ZoneArea': 39.0,
               'FieldOpID': 142925.0,
               'FieldID': 632891.0,
               'Id': 0.0, 
               'ZoneMax': 0.41}}, 
       {'geometry': 
           {'type': 'Polygon', 
            'coordinates': (((389233.9246038566, 5521227.342725102), (389220.1242731925, 5521226.14937102), (389192.8088917327, 5521233.278642576), (389186.0853303991, 5521234.682576215), (389186.82531866303, 5521236.313554208), 

etc.
```

The above GeoJSON object is put into a map before being passed to the `unary_union` function:

```
def to_shape(feature):
    geom = shape(feature['geometry'])
    if geom.is_valid:
        return geom
    return geom.buffer(0)

def get_shapes(zone_map_utm):
    return map(to_shape, zone_map_utm['features'])

...
x = unary_union(get_shapes(geojson_dict))
```

The error being raised is this:

```
File "/home/james/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/ops.py", line 147, in unary_union
  subs[i] = g._geom
AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute '_geom'
```

The shapely version is 1.6.4

Can anyone comment as to what may be amiss?

Comment: Try using `list(map(...))` instead of just `map(...)`.  Pretty much anything that used to return a list in Python 2 now returns an iterator in Python 3, perhaps unary_union can't handle that.

Comment: see   [Getting a map() to return a list in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1303354)